# Django custom permissions does not added

Tags: python, django

I have a class called TypedItem

```
class TypedItem(BaseModel):
    type = models.CharField(choices=['g', 'k'], max_length=1)

    class Meta(BaseModel.Meta):
        permissions = [
            ('change_type', 'Can change type')
        ]
```

I called `python manage.py makemigrations` and it creates a migration;

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='TypedItem',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ('type', models.CharField(choices=['g', 'k'], default='g', max_length=1)),
    ],
    options={
        'permissions': [('change_type', 'Can change type')],
        'abstract': False,
    },
    bases=(dirtyfields.dirtyfields.DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model),
),
```

But I can't see my custom permission in database after I called `python manage.py migrate`. Am I have to do something extra?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. It's a bug within `django-admin-view-permission` package.