# How to add custom permissions to Django admin Groups page?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I want to create a Group that contains multiple custom permissions related to a custom Account model (extended from base User), then restrict access to routes/pages to Accounts only within that group.

I have added the following custom permissions to my Account model (which is a working extension of the base AUTH_USER_MODEL)...

```py
class Account(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date Created')
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_access_x_pages",
                "To provide access to X pages"),
            ("can_access_y_pages",
                "To provide access to Y pages"),
            ("can_access_z_pages",
                "To provide access to Z pages"),
        )
```

... but those permissions do not show up on the "New Group" page on Django Admin:
[image]

Based on [this GeeksForGeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-user-groups-custom-permissions-django/#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20Django,Python3), once the permissions have been added, they should simply be displayed. Any idea what I am missing?

This [self-answered StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960761/django-custom-permissions-does-not-added) from 2016 is the same issue, but that OP cited a bug in `django-admin-view-permission` as the problem, but that is all they wrote.

**Edit: I checked my Adminer view of the database, and I do not see the new permissions there, so I'm guessing that they have not been migrated?**

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question... sure enough, I just hadn't migrated the changes. Woops.